# Additional Information showing up on the bottom of the product page tab

Tags: magento2, tabs

How do I remove "More Information" it's showing up on the bottom of the product page. where is this coming from? it's in the main tabs which is fine, but separately it's also showing up at the bottom, before the footer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml` which indicates this is from core template. Just create a override for this template and comment out line 22 is ok.

Comment: i comment out the line 22. its still there, without the table.

Comment: You may have other file that overrides this file

Comment: how do i find that?

Comment: I don't know which theme you're using. The path should look like `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`